# COUNTIF with absolute column, relative row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this table and I want B1 and B2 to display the sum where D1, F1 and H1, and D2, F2 and H2 are bigger than 0, respectively. I will be inserting two columns to the left of C on a regular basis, and I don't want the column references in the formula to be updated when the columns are shifted, but if B2 becomes B3 when a row is added above it, I will need the formula to be updated for the row and check the values in D3, F3 and H3, or if I add rows below it, I want to be able to drag down and get the formula copied with incremental row values. I tried INDIRECT with and without &CELL("address", E2) but I couldn't get it to work as I wanted it.

```
  A      B (Sum)  C            D  E            F  G            H
1 Josh   3        Some number  6  Some number  4  Some number  3
2 Fiona  2        Some number  1  Some number  0  Some number  4
```

Comment: In `B1` try: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISEVEN(COLUMN(C1:H1))*(C1:H1>0))`. I'm thinking it should be possible through `QUERY` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) to get absolute column references, and [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) to count if each referenced cell is bigger than 0:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,0,2),">0")+COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,0,4),">0")+COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,0,6),">0")
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but try `=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,1,1,500))`. That way you refer to the cell itself so whenever you add columns it's not affected. I used 500 arbitrarily since it's simple. Adjust as needed.